# PHP Preg_match() Unknown Modifier Url

Tags: php, preg-match

I got this error message:

```
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\easyblog\wp-content\themes\easyblog\inc\widget\flickr.php on line 225
```

Source code in here :

```
// Screen name or RSS in $username?
if (!preg_match("/http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/", $username))
$url = "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=".urlencode($user_id)."&format=".$flickrformat."&lang=en-us".$tags;
else
$url = $username."&format=".$flickrformat.$tags;
```

Can someone help me, please!

Comment: I already try using this code but still error:

`if (!preg_match("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds", $username))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the forward slashes in your expression:

```
"/http:\/\/api.flickr.com\/services\/feeds/"
```

Comment: You need to show how to do that

Comment: I already try using this code but still error:

`if (!preg_match("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds", $username))`

Comment: Solved Problem :)

Thank you so much Pe de Leao for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `/` delimiter, then you must escape all `/` character if used inside pattern, for avoiding this you can use another delimiter such as `#`

```
"#http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds#"
```

However, your pattern needs escaping:

```
"/http:\/\/api.flickr.com\/services\/feeds/"
```